# How to fill only half of border-bottom?

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients

I have several `<li>` listed inline, each with the following property:

```
border-bottom-color: #eee;
```

I am trying to target first and last `<li>` and fill their `border-bottom` with `#eee` but only *in half*. As a result, the bottom border of the 1st `<li>` will be filled by 50% starting from right, and the bottom border of the last `<li>` will be filled by 50% starting from left.

How can I accomplish this? Except maybe just adding a div with `height: 1px` below my `ul`.

Comment: A gradient border might work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you may use a `linear-gradient`, `background-size`, `background-repeat` and `background:position`:

```css
p {
  border:solid;
  width:350px;
  margin:auto;
  border-bottom:none;
  background:linear-gradient(black,black) bottom /* left or right or else */ no-repeat;
  background-size:50% 3px;
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

It even can be animated:http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC

else; [box-shadow](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oxzKJp) or border-image could be also involved.

Answer (score 4):

As j08691 had indicated in comments, it might be a better idea to use a `linear-gradient` for this one (or you could use a half width pseudo-element and position it).

**Using** `linear-gradient` **as** `background-image`: (has better browser support than `border-image`)

All that is required is to create a gradient of the required thickness (2px in the below snippet), set the width of the gradient image to 50% of element's width and then position the image.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eee, #eee); /* no color change, just one color */
  background-size: 100% 2px; /* 2px is thickness of the border */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* don't repeat background */
  background-position: 100% 100%; /* by default position w.r.t right bottom */
}
ul li:first-child,
ul li:last-child {
  background-size: 50% 2px; /* set bg size as half width for first and last li */
}
ul li:last-child {
  background-position: 0% 100%; /* override position w.r.t left bottom for last li */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Using** `linear-gradient` **as** `border-image`:

For this approach, we need to create a gradient that is transparent for one half, `#eee` for the other and set it as the value for the `border-image` property.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}
ul li:first-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #eee 50%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
ul li:last-child {
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #eee 50%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
  <li>Test Content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pseudo elements to solve this.

Simply place a `:before` on the `:first-child` and an `:after` on the `:last-child` then apply the border to those pseudo elements like so:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  padding: .5em 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

li:first-child:before,
li:last-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #eee;
  width: 50%;
}

li:first-child:before {
  left: 0;
}

li:last-child:before {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a codepen link too if you would like to play about with the styles:

[CODEPEN LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLadbB)